# How to sync properties on a view model, but stop syncing after user changes the second?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, synchronization, viewmodel, inotifypropertychanged

**Requirement 1**

Let's say I have some view model with two `DateTime` properties, `Start` and `End`. I would like for `End` to be set to some offset from `Start`, and for this to be maintained even as `Start` changes. This is easy enough by listening to the property notification for `Start` and then setting `End`.

#### Requirement 2

Now, let's add the fun part: I want to be able to stop adjusting `End` if the user explicitly changes it. Put another way, let's say it's an airline reservation system, and we want to set the end date to 3 days later (based on the average length of stay), but if the user explicitly sets the end date to a specific date, then when he/she sets the start date again, the end date stays).

#### The Problem

On first thought, it would seem you could just listen for `End`'s notification and set some value that the handler will see when handling `Start`, and say "ok, I won't adjust `End`. The problem is that `End` doesn't know *why* it is being changed, so the handler for `End`'s change will blithely set the stop-changing condition immediately. This violates requirement #1.

How can I satisfy both requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have a flag `AutoAdjust` that tells you if you should adjust `End` when `Start` changes. `AutoAdjust` is initially `true`.

Whenever `End` is set, if the interval between `Start` and `End` is different than the "default" interval, set `AutoAdjust` to `false`.

Whenever `Start` is set, if `AutoAdjust` is `true` then adjust the value of `End`.

Note that with this scheme, it will never be possible to set `AutoAdjust` back to `true` once it flips to `false`. This is intentional, and IMHO more intuitive than allowing `AutoAdjust` to flip back -- the user can easily reason that the end date has stopped auto-adjusting because they manually modified it, but it's not as intuitive to think that if they set it back to its "auto" value it will start auto-adjusting again.

Comment: Good solution, and I agree with your last paragraph.